# MySQL Workbench :: Can't add a second foreign key to existing table

Tags: mysql

Apologies in advance for what is prob a duplicate post - I can't find my exact issue elsewhere.  I'm taking a SQL course and using MySQL Workbench 6.3 as my sandbox.  In my class project, I'm creating "Courses", "Professors" and "Teaches" tables.  Here's the first two, abridged:

```
// CREATE DATABASE `project1'...
CREATE TABLE `courses`    ( `cid` int(11) NOT NULL, ...more... PRIMARY KEY (`cid`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `professors` ( `ssn` int(11) NOT NULL, ...more... PRIMARY KEY (`ssn`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The "Teaches" tables is simple enough:

```
CREATE TABLE `teaches` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ssn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`,`ssn`),
  KEY `ssn_idx` (`ssn`),
  CONSTRAINT `ssn` FOREIGN KEY (`ssn`) REFERENCES `professors` (`ssn`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

All of the SQL above is successful.  But my problem is that "Teaches" needs a second foreign key back to "Courses."  I would have thought this would do it:

```
ALTER TABLE `project1`.`teaches` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `cid`
  FOREIGN KEY (`cid`)
  REFERENCES `project1`.`courses` (`cid`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

But MySQL hates it:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-1060_1b'
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `project1`.`teaches` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `cid`
  FOREIGN KEY (`cid`)
  REFERENCES `project1`.`courses` (`cid`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

I'm baffled because I have other tables with two foreign key relations, and I'm not hitting this issue with them.  (Yes, I've cloned their SQL create statements, but no luck.)  The problem is described as "`duplicate key in table '#sql-1060_1b'`" but I can't figure out what table #sql-1060-1b might be.  Any guidance?

Comment: How this is SQL Server?

Comment: Rename your key :)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen  That did it!  Man, sometimes its the simplest things...  thanks a million.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Norbert van Nobelen, who solved the problem - renaming the "Course" attribute from "cid" to "mycid" did the trick.